# Strange artifacts after CILanczosScaleTransform

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-image

I'm trying to do image scaling using Core Image, using Lanczos Scale Transform filter.
It is fine when I'm doing scaleup. But on scaledown and saving to JPEG I found a class of images which produces strange noise artifacts and behavior.

For inputScale multiples to 0.5: 0.5, 0.25, 0.125 etc it is always fine. 
For others inputScale values,it's broken.

When I'm saving to TIFF,PNG,JPEG2000 or draw on screen - it's fine.
When I'm saving to JPG or BMP - it's broken.

I uploaded sample images:
([original, 4272x2848, 3.4Mb](http://www.zoomfoot.com/get/package/517e2423-7795-4239-a166-03d507ec51d8))
[http://www.zoomfoot.com/get/package/517e2423-7795-4239-a166-03d507ec51d8]

([scaled with noise, 1920x1280, 2.2Mb](http://www.zoomfoot.com/get/package/6eb64d33-3a30-4e8d-9953-67ce1e7d7ef9))
[http://www.zoomfoot.com/get/package/6eb64d33-3a30-4e8d-9953-67ce1e7d7ef9]

It also, pretty good reproducible on 'sunset' images.

I've tried couple more ways to scale images. Using CIAffineTransform and drawing using NSImage itself. Both provides results without any noise.

Here is the code I was using for scaling & saving:

================= Lanczos ==============

```
- (NSImage *) scaleLanczosImage:(NSString *)path
       Width:(int) desiredWidth
      Height:(int) desiredHeight
{
 CIImage *image=[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:
       [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

CIFilter *scaleFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILanczosScaleTransform"];
 int originalHeight=[image extent].size.height;
 int originalWidth=[image extent].size.width;

float yScale=(float)desiredHeight / (float)originalHeight; 
 float xScale=(float)desiredWidth / (float)originalWidth; 
 float scale=fminf(yScale, xScale);

[scaleFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:scale]
    forKey:@"inputScale"]; 
 [scaleFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]
    forKey:@"inputAspectRatio"];
 [scaleFilter setValue: image
    forKey:@"inputImage"];

image = [scaleFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:image];
 NSMutableDictionary *options=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] 
               forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];

[options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSImageProgressive];
 NSData* jpegData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType
           properties:options];

[jpegData writeToFile:@"/Users/dmitry/tmp/img_4389-800x600.jpg" atomically:YES];
}

================= NSImage ==============

```
- (void) scaleNSImage:(NSString *)path
    Width:(int) desiredWidth
      Height:(int) desiredHeight
{
 NSImage *sourceImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 NSImage *resizedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: 
        NSMakeSize(desiredWidth, desiredHeight)];
```

NSSize originalSize = [sourceImage size];

[resizedImage lockFocus];
 [sourceImage drawInRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, desiredWidth, desiredHeight) 
       fromRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, originalSize.width, originalSize.height) 
      operation: NSCompositeSourceOver fraction: 1.0];

[resizedImage unlockFocus];

NSMutableDictionary *options=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] 
                 forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];

[options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSImageProgressive];

NSBitmapImageRep *rep  = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] 
            initWithData:[resizedImage TIFFRepresentation]];

NSData* jpegData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType
           properties:options];

[jpegData writeToFile:@"~/nsimg_4389-800x600.jpg" atomically:YES];

}

If anyone can explain or suggest something here, i'm really appreciate this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are some quirks with scaling with CIImage. Will [this](http://www.gigliwood.com/weblog/Cocoa/Core_Image,_part_2.html?seemore=y) post by Dan Wood help?

Comment: yeah, i've tried this, but it is something different. I'm not sure why  i'm getting green net over the sunset in jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that due to its nature, the hardware Core Image renderer has some odd quirks when rendering for anything but on-screen display. So, you are recommended to use the software renderer for other situations.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2005/qa1416.html

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely a CoreImage bug.  File it at bugreport.apple.com